# alignas(64) is slower/causes pessimization

Tags: c++, c++17, alignment

While reading beginner material/tutorials relevant to lock-free programming (and after doing some exercises) I found this happening.

Given the following piece of code (where the only difference is pretty much using `alignas(64)` in `struct node2` while manually "aligning" in `struct node1`)

```
#include <mutex>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

struct node1 {
    node1* next{ nullptr };
    int value{ 0 };
private:
    char align_bytes[64 - sizeof(node1*) - sizeof(value)];
};

struct alignas(64) node2 {
    node2* next{ nullptr };
    int value{ 0 };
};

static_assert(sizeof(node1) == 64);
static_assert(sizeof(node2) == 64);

std::mutex node_mutex;
node1* locked1{nullptr};
node2* locked2{nullptr};

auto handmade = [](benchmark::State& state) {
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        node1* new_node{ new node1() };
        node1* old{ nullptr };
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(node_mutex);
            old = locked1;
            locked1 = new_node;
        }
        delete old;
    }
};

auto aligned = [](benchmark::State& state) {
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        node2* new_node{ new node2() };
        node2* old{ nullptr };
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(node_mutex);
            old = locked2;
            locked2 = new_node;
        }
        delete old;
    }
};

BENCHMARK(handmade)->Threads(1)->UseRealTime();
BENCHMARK(aligned)->Threads(1)->UseRealTime();

BENCHMARK(handmade)->Threads(2)->UseRealTime();
BENCHMARK(aligned)->Threads(2)->UseRealTime();

BENCHMARK(handmade)->Threads(4)->UseRealTime();
BENCHMARK(aligned)->Threads(4)->UseRealTime();

BENCHMARK(handmade)->Threads(8)->UseRealTime();
BENCHMARK(aligned)->Threads(8)->UseRealTime();

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

When compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror -O3 -o alignas_bench alignas.cpp -lbenchmark
```

using `g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`

Gave me these results

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Werror -O3 -o alignas_bench alignas.cpp -lbenchmark
./alignas_bench
2021-08-26 19:52:16
Running ./alignas_bench
Run on (4 X 2300 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 24K (x4)
  L1 Instruction 32K (x4)
  L2 Unified 1024K (x2)
Load Average: 1.01, 1.13, 1.02
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                             Time             CPU   Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
handmade/real_time/threads:1       53.4 ns         53.4 ns     12753880
aligned/real_time/threads:1         198 ns          198 ns      3503060

handmade/real_time/threads:2        134 ns          267 ns      5135622
aligned/real_time/threads:2         315 ns          630 ns      2073218

handmade/real_time/threads:4        207 ns          754 ns      3949912
aligned/real_time/threads:4         325 ns         1260 ns      2111384

handmade/real_time/threads:8        202 ns          807 ns      3555384
aligned/real_time/threads:8         327 ns         1303 ns      2268416
```

I cannot explain why the "handmade alignment" `node1` object appears to do exactly the same work 50-100% faster, when the only difference appears to be the `alignas(64)`

Answer (score 3):

Increasing the size of an object does not increase its alignment requirement. Your "handmade" class isn't aligned to 64 byte boundary.

Benchmarking is difficult. You changed the layout of the memory and that can have drastic incidental effects on performance depending on how that layout interacts with things such as page boundaries and cache lines etc. You cannot make meaningful conclusions about the measurements unless you eliminate the effect of layout biases.

---

Here is my guess at the reason for potential difference (this is just a guess, the difference could be caused by many other things):

64 probably exceeds `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__` on your system, so the memory allocation uses a different function `operator new(std::size_t, std::align_val_t)` instead of `operator new(std::size_t)`. Perhaps this function is a bit slower.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My understanding was that it is good to align object into 64 bytes, cause this is how long a cache line is (and you can avoid false sharing this way). I also did a `static_assert(sizeof(node1) == 64);`. Is this thinking not valid?

Comment: you aren't actually doing any work with the allocated objects though, your benchmark is basically testing the performance of the heap and mutexes, the heap is having to do extra work to provide the requested alignment

Comment: @george_ptr `and you can avoid false sharing this way` You make no accesses to a shared nodes, so the alignment has no effect on false sharing in your example `sizeof(node1) Is this thinking not valid?` That is not valid for checking the alignment of a type. You need to use `alignof` instead of `sizeof`

Comment: @george_ptr Size does not imply alignment, try `std::alignment_of<T>::value`. AFAIK the rules are that all members must be aligned as per their requirements.

Comment: Just setting the alignment, without modifying `node1` in any other way causes the difference [benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/q-Ral2D83qwa6ArN-XD-bh0P2rA). So the size is not relevant here.